# Webcam not working properly (wrong resolution)

Tags: debian, resolution, camera, amd-graphics

Since a while, I haven't been able to get the correct resolution of my laptop's integrated webcam. The laptop model is a Thinkpad T495, I'm using Debian testing, and the kernel is `6.0.0-2-amd64`.

The only available resolution is 160x120, but I should be able to use a 1920x1080 resolution. At some point in life I was having the proper resolution, but after updating to a `5.10.*` kernel I started having issues: sometimes low, sometimes the desired resolution, but since the `5.12.*` kernel I've only had the low resolution.

This is the webcam information

```bash
~$ inxi -Gxx
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Mobile Series]
    vendor: Lenovo driver: amdgpu v: kernel arch: GCN-5 pcie: speed: 8 GT/s
    lanes: 16 ports: active: eDP-1 empty: DP-1,DP-2,HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 06:00.0
    chip-ID: 1002:15d8 temp: 55.0 C
  Device-2: IMC Networks Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 4-2.1:4 chip-ID: 13d3:56a6
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: xfwm v: 4.16.1 driver:
    X: loaded: amdgpu unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa dri: radeonsi gpu: amdgpu
    display-ID: :0.0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 96
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 mapped: eDP model: InfoVision Optronics/Kunshan 0x057d
    res: 1920x1080 dpi: 158 diag: 355mm (14")
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.0 renderer: AMD Radeon Vega 10 Graphics
    (raven LLVM 14.0.6 DRM 3.48 6.0.0-2-amd64) direct render: Yes
```

v4l2 lists only one resolution:

```bash
~$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
    Type: Video Capture

    [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
        Size: Discrete 160x120
            Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
```

I tried installing/re-installing/removing and installing again `firmware-amd-graphics , libv4l-0, cheese, guvcview` and rebooting, but that doesn't works.

Any suggestion on what I could try now?

Comment: Not got a clue other than loading the `uvcvideo` with the `quirks` option.

Comment: `Since a while, I haven't been able to set up the resolution of my laptop's integrated webcam properly.` ... does that mean that you were able to set the resolution before?

Comment: @jsotola, no, it means that before it was working properly and I was able to choose between two different resolutions, the lower one and the higher/correct one. I should re-phare it